What should I do if my result is rejected by a Q2 journal?
I recently authored a research paper proposing a novel algorithm that outperforms a previously published Q1-ranked algorithm by a logarithmic factor. My approach involves two primary contributions: a novel lemma for a subproblem and a modified algorithm that leverages a unique monotonicity property of the existing state-of-the-art method. While the core results and analysis span five pages, the overall paper extends to 11 pages due to a necessary overview of relevant prior work.
My paper has been rejected by three journals,two Q1 and one Q2. One Q2 reviewer deemed the work suitable for publication with revisions, while the other rejected it, expressing concerns about the relatively small improvement compared to the existing state-of-the-art, which reduced the complexity of the algorithm from $O(N^{3x}logN)$ to $O(N^{x}logN)$.

How can I choose the next journal to send my results?


Did you do the revisions suggested by one journal? If not, why not?

@Buffy. Yes I did the revisions suggested by the first reviewer. The second reviewer suggested adding more results to the paper

This whole Qx ranking is questionable. Some of my best results are in Q3/4 papers and I got really knowledgeable and constructive reviews from there which improved the papers a lot. I got useless reviews from high-ranked outlets. Develop a portfolio of results, rather than just aiming to get this one result in high-ranked papers.

Your description of your approach reminds me of Symposium on Simplicity in Algorithms (https://www.siam.org/conferences-events/siam-conferences/sosa25/ ), maybe this would be a fitting venue?

As it stands, this question has too much math-specific detail. Please edit to be generalizable.

This may be obvious but most journal editors and reviewers care much more about the relevance of your result to their specific community of readers than about any perceived Qx-ranking based quality of your result.
Apparently your result was evaluated as not sufficiently relevant / important for these specific 3 journals that you submitted to. Usually that means you have to find a more specialized journal that serves a community to which your result is relevant. Consider the following strategies:

Which journals are you citing in your manuscript?
Which articles are citing the same sources as you do, and in which journals have these been published?

Going through the resulting journal lists (or maybe conferences) can help to identify other possible publication venues, which may be any of Q1, Q2, Q3, ... irrespective of your previous submissions.
In your specific case, I assume you already submitted to the Q1 journal in which the earlier result was published, but got rejected. In that case, if you think you can appeal to a similar community with your result, an additional strategy would be to look for other journals that are publishing articles citing this Q1 journal.
I'm not an expert in theoretical computer science, but it seems your result is more important for applications with large N and small x. If you can identify such applications, another way to proceed might be to target your algorithm to these applications and look for a more application-oriented journal, where your improvement might be perceived as more relevant.
